# How To Access Child Window URL from Parent Window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am redirecting my child window to another url after launching. Actually I am submitting the data to another domain. That domain processing the data and sends to new domain. I need to catch the new domain URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do that. You can't access frames/windows from different origin - that's simply not safe and the browser won't let you.

You could try to work it out differently.

For example, I believe you could have your server side get the other website for you and serve it in your own domain. If you decide to do that, you need to have the reference to your child window first (e.g. `var win = window.open(url);`) - but still, that needs to be in your domain.

Another way would be to simply post your data using your server side language and then try to read the received page (also using server side). In PHP for example, you could accomplish that with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

### Edit

Just came upon [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) functionality. If the other websites are yours, I think that's the way to go (well, maybe except the limited compatibility in IE 8 & 9: [Can I use postMessage](http://caniuse.com/#search=postmessage)).

Comment: +1 for your answer since the author didnt have the chance to appreciate your input