# Call a function in parent window when the url in child window changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have opened a child window like this:

```
let child = window.open("http://localhost:4200/test", "myWindowName", "height=200,width=200");
```

Based on the operation performed in child window, the child window url changes to /test/success and a query param is appended at the end, which I need to read in the parent window.

I tried to add hashchange eventlistner but nothing happens.

I tried both ways:

```
child.addEventListener('hashchange',this.callFunc.bind(this));
```

and

```
child.onhashchange = this.callFunc;
```

But the callFunc is never called:

```
callFunc(){
    console.log("Calledd!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
 }
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26987995/how-to-access-child-window-url-from-parent-window